# What are the specific behaviours of runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Regarding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

The MSDN documentation [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691427%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#CommunityContent) about the attribute:

> A read/write boolean value. true if all managed modules are run for every request; otherwise, false. The default is false.

This [article](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) describes  a bit more about its "true" value behaviour:

> This highly recommended fix can cause other problems. These problems come in the form of making all your registered HTTP modules run on every request, not just managed requests (e.g. .aspx). This means modules will run on ever .jpg .gif .css .html .pdf etc.

Now about: *runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="**false**"* ...

My question -- that the MSDN docs don't seem to get into specifics about --  is how does the false value behave other than just the general description of not running all managed modules for every request?

For example, does "false" skip some modules yet run the request through a bunch of others; does the request stop on the first module that processes it like a handler, etc.?  And how do unmanaged modules fit into the behaviour?

Overall is there a good guide or description for this behaviour?

Comment: You may be interested in Rick Strahl's post on the property http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78

Comment: After skimming Rick Strahl's excellent Blog post about this topic I'd just like to know how the heck Microsoft gets away with giving us only a one-liner in its definitive MSDN documentation?! >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691427(v=vs.90).aspx#CommunityContent They must have published the details somewhere.

Comment: @RussCam can you drop that blog post link below as an official answer. It'll be worth something. Thanks.

Comment: Will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [Rick Strahl's blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78) post on the subject as there are some nuances to what `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"` does:

> runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" - different than you might
> think! What's not quite so obvious is what happens when you set the
> runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false". You probably would expect
> that non-ASP.NET requests no longer get funneled through the ASP.NET
> Module pipeline. But that's not what actually happens.
>
> For example, if I create a module like this:
>
> ```
> <add name="SharewareModule" type="HowAspNetWorks.SharewareMessageModule"  />
> ```
>
> by default it will
> fire against ALL requests regardless of the
> runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests flag. Even if the value
> runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false", the module is fired with
> unmanaged requests going through it. Not quite as expected.
>
> So what is the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests really good for?
> It's essentially an override for managedHandler preCondition. If I
> declare my handler in web.config like this:
>
> ```xml
>    <add name="SharewareModule" type="HowAspNetWorks.SharewareMessageModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
> ```
>
> and then set
>
> ```xml
>  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" >
> ```
>
> my module only fires
> against managed requests. If I switch the flag to `true`, now my module
> ends up handling all IIS requests that are passed through from IIS.
>
> The moral of the story here is that if you intend to only look at
> ASP.NET content, you should always set the
> `preCondition="managedHandler"` attribute to ensure that only managed
> requests are fired on this module. But even if you do this, realize
> that `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` can override this
> setting, so your module has to anticipate handling any kind of
> request.

Comment: code is not shown under "For example, if I create a module like this:"

Answer (score 2):

FWIW,

[Scott Hanselman has a good post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) about the setting and what it means. He also has some specific reasons for its existence and why you might not need it.